Unpredictable variable context in Typescript classes
I am trying to create a class in Typescript (React Native) that manages modals in a stack as to not have the modals consume too much memory (use case might not be super important). I am declaring an instance of the class and then pushing and popping from the class. However, when I call the push and pop methods, the stack contents are never what I expect. The 'this" keyword is never pointing to the correct instance of the class...
I have done some reading up on classes in typescript and followed every suggestion I have found so far. Maybe I am trying to use typescript as if is java and that's my problem...
Here is my ModalManager class:
type modalData = {
    modalFunction: Function; //Function that loads the modal
    modalParameters: Array<any>; //stack of paramers for function
}
  
class ModalManager {
    private modalMap: Map<string, modalData> = new Map<string, modalData>();
    private defaultView: ReactNode = <View></View>;
    private modalStack: Stack<string> = new Stack<string>([""]);
    private renderCallback: Function;
  
    constructor(renderCallback: Function) {
      this.renderCallback = renderCallback;
      this.setDefaultView = this.setDefaultView.bind(this);
      this.registerModal = this.registerModal.bind(this);
      this.pushModal = this.pushModal.bind(this);
      this.popModal = this.popModal.bind(this);
      this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    }
  
    setDefaultView(defaultView: ReactNode){
      this.defaultView = defaultView;
    }
  
    registerModal(modalName: string, modalFunction: (params: any[], containerModal: ModalManager) => ReactNode){
        if (modalName != "") {
            this.modalMap.set(modalName, {modalFunction: modalFunction, modalParameters: new Array()} as modalData);
        }
    }
  
    pushModal(modalName: string, modalParameters: any){
      //Make sure modal is registered
      if (this.modalMap.has(modalName)) {
        //put modal at top of modal stack
        this.modalStack.push(modalName);
        console.log("1", this.modalStack.peek())
        //put modal parameters in modal parameters stack
        this.modalMap.get(modalName)?.modalParameters.unshift(modalParameters);
        //Cause rerender
        this.renderCallback(modalName);
      }
    }
  
    popModal(){
        console.log("4", this.modalStack.peek())

        if (this.modalStack.peek() != "") {
            this.modalStack.pop()
            console.log("3", this.modalStack.peek())

            this.renderCallback(this.modalStack.peek())
        }
    }
  
    render(currentModal: string){
        console.log("2", this.modalStack.peek())

      return (
        <View>
          <View>
          {(currentModal != "") ? 
            this.modalMap.get(currentModal)?.modalFunction(this.modalMap.get(currentModal)?.modalParameters, this) : <View/>
          }
          </View>
          {this.defaultView}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

Here is my stack class:
class StackNode<T> {
    next: StackNode<T> | null = null;
    value: T;

    constructor(value: T, next: StackNode<T> | null) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}


class Stack<T> {
    private top: StackNode<T> | null = null;

    constructor(starter: Array<T>) {
        this.push = this.push.bind(this);
        this.pop = this.pop.bind(this);
        this.peek = this.peek.bind(this);

        starter.forEach((item) => {
            this.push(item);
        })
    }

    push(value: T){
        let newTop: StackNode<T> = new StackNode<T>(value, this.top);
        this.top = newTop;
    }

    pop(){
        if (this.top != null) {
            this.top = this.top.next;
        }
    }

    peek(){
        return this.top?.value;
    }
}

And here is my app code:
const [currentModal, setCurrentModal] = useState("");

  const containerModal: ModalManager = new ModalManager(setCurrentModal)

  containerModal.setDefaultView(
    <View>
      <Button title="Open modal 1" onPress={() => {containerModal.pushModal("test", {name: "Eli", value: 10, key: "secret"})}} />
    </View>
  );

  containerModal.registerModal("test", testModalFunction);
  containerModal.registerModal("test2", test2ModalFunction);

  return (
    <View>
      {containerModal.render(currentModal)}
    </View>
  );
};

I have tried changing my methods from this style: () => {}, to the style it is now. I have tried to bind methods that you see present in the code. I really am scratching my head on this one, it seems like a pretty basic thing I'm trying to do.
Thanks for reading if you made it this far.
edit I suspect that it could be due to my render function where I am passing "this" as a parameter to the modal builder function. The modal then calls methods on the "this" that is passed to it and that's where I'm getting bad behavior. Still not sure how to fix it...

There are so, so many problems here. None of this makes sense in a React context. You are "cutting against the grain" of the language/framework. Much as if I have a bunch of data-only classes (C structs) and helper classes with a bunch of static methods (C functions) javac might accept my code but clearly I'm not thinking in Java, I'm just writing C in Java. Recommend you throw away all of this code, do some React tutorials (learn to think in React and Javascript), and start over.

I'm not sure if you should be worried about modal memory usage; and I'm not really sure how your ModalManager does anything to preserve memory (I am not the brightest dev)

containerModal should probably be stored in a ref, and then in an useEffect set default views and register your modals. As the code currently exist, at every re-render containerModal is recreated, the default view is set, and then modals are registered. That might be why you're getting undesireable behavior

But it would follow the react paradigm  for ModalManager to be a component that with the following props: modals (modal registration/components), initialIndex (replaces setDefaultView, assuming that defaultView is actually in modals array), currentModal (changing this value is how you cycle  between modals)
